# How to open chrome://inspect devices using command prompt

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, command-prompt

I want to open chrome://inspect from windows command prompt.

Here my use case is I want to open the chrome browser from command prompt(using ProcessBuilder in java) and chrome://inspect link so i can see the devices attached to my system

so i tried opening chrome://inspect using this command

start chrome chrome://inspect which is not working

if I replace chrome://inspect with any url it's working.

Can any one let me know how to do this from command prompt or any other possible ways to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome URLs can't be  opened from the command line. They must be typed by a user into the omnibar.

Comment: Is there any other way so I can open it. I want to open it using Java( But not with selenium)

Comment: They *must* be typed by a user into the omnibar. The only possible way around it (which is being fixed in the Material redesign of settings) is to have it auto-open as a default tab on startup. However, this can cause annoyance issues, so chrome URLs will be filtered out of that so don't rely upon it.